# python - how to properly quote sql string

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

How do I properly quote this string this postgres sql syntax
within my python script which uses psycopg2's `cur.execute ("SELECT .. ")`

Postgres sql:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE RENAME ' || tablename || ' TO ' || 
  REGEXP_REPLACE ( tablename, '_foo$', '_bar' ) || ';'
FROM pg_tables
WHERE tablename LIKE '%_foo';
```

Within my python script:

```
  cur.execute("SELECT 'ALTER TABLE RENAME ' || tablename || ' TO ' ||
                REGEXP_REPLACE ( tablename, '_foo$', '_bar' ) || ';'
                FROM pg_tables
                WHERE tablename LIKE '%_foo'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, add line breaks:

```
cur.execute("SELECT 'ALTER TABLE RENAME ' || tablename || ' TO ' || \
             REGEXP_REPLACE ( tablename, '_foo$', '_bar' ) || ';' \
             FROM pg_tables \
             WHERE tablename LIKE '%_foo'")
```

Comment: Better yet, use triple quotes (`"""`) to avoid backslash escapes for multiline strings.